# z index won't work on ionic ion-toolbar and ion-card(within ion-content)

Tags: css, ionic-framework

This the css code
ion-toolbar { --background: #e1b12c; color: #FFFFFF; padding-bottom: 200px; border-radius: 0 0 20% 20%; .bordered { --border-radius: 10px; } }

ion-col { padding: 0; }

ion-content { --background: #f6f6f6; }

ion-card { margin-top: -180px; z-index: 10; padding: 6px; box-shadow: none; box-shadow: 0px 3px 45px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); border-radius: 40px; overflow: visible; ion-img { width: 240px; margin: -50px auto auto -30px; }

}

Comment: Please share your code as a stack snippet to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: sorry for late reply and thanks for your comment, I have resolved the issue, but integrating the ion-header inside ion-content then I can apply z index of two containers at the same level